# How to dynamically change the template in aurelia / click to edit table row?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

With knockout I could dynamically change the template of a table row so that when I clicked on it, the row would become editable using an edit template. 
No navigation, no routing, just assigning the row a new template. 
How do I do this in aurelia?

Comment: Needs to be interactive, when the user clicks on the row. I assume something like click.trigger="$parent.toggleTemplate(item)"

Comment: Jeremy's answer is as always perfect. I've written up a blog on advanced table templating here in case you wanted to go further with this. http://davismj.me/blog/advanced-tables/.

Comment: Went With
<table>
 <tr repeat.for="r of ['A','B','A','B']" as-element="compose" view='./template_${r}.html'>
</table>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how you could accomplish this using the `if` binding command:

https://gist.run/?id=2408b065ecfac30ff2b1034ea8da800d

[image: screenshot]

---

### Code:

app.js

```js
export class App {
  editing = null;
  
  planets = [
    { name: 'Mercury', diameter: 3032, distance: 35983610 },
    { name: 'Venus', diameter: 7521, distance: 67232360 },
    { name: 'Earth', diameter: 7926, distance: 92957100 },
    { name: 'Mars', diameter: 4222, distance: 141635300 },
    { name: 'Jupiter', diameter: 88846, distance: 483632000 },
    { name: 'Saturn', diameter: 74898, distance: 888188000 },
    { name: 'Uranus', diameter: 31763, distance: 1783950000 },
    { name: 'Neptune', diameter: 30778, distance: 2798842000 }];
  
  edit(planet) {
    this.editing = planet;
  }
}
```

app.html

```HTML
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Planet</td>
        <td>Diameter (mi)</td>
        <td>Distance to Sun (mi)</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="planet of planets" click.delegate="edit(planet)">
        <!-- read-only mode -->
        <td if.bind="editing !== planet">${planet.name}</td>
        <td if.bind="editing !== planet">${planet.diameter}</td>
        <td if.bind="editing !== planet">${planet.distance}</td>
        
        <!-- edit-mode -->
        <td if.bind="editing === planet"><input value.bind="planet.name" type="text"></td>
        <td if.bind="editing === planet"><input value.bind="planet.diameter" type="number"></td>
        <td if.bind="editing === planet"><input value.bind="planet.distance" type="number"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

css:

```css
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody > tr > td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: poor pluto got kicked out :(

Comment: Tried to solve this myself but this solution is much cleaner.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you can use a view strategy to dynamically choose the view for the view model.

http://aurelia.io/docs.html#compose - scroll down to the part about view strategy

What if you want to determine the view dynamically based on data though? or runtime conditions? You can do that too by implementing a getViewStrategy() method on your view-model. It can return a relative path to the view or an instance of a ViewStrategy for custom view loading behavior. The nice part is that this method is executed after the activate callback, so you have access to the model data when determining the view.